# fork() a process and share all but certain memory

Tags: memory, static, fork, shared-memory

This is a very conceptual question, so forgive me if it sounds vague.

I am investigating an application where code with some static data needs to be executed concurrently in a shared context. In particular that code will make call backs to the host application and alter its internal state. Adapting the code to use no static data is very costly. So I thought about wrapping each execution in its own process via fork() and sharing all but the *known* static data. Is that possible? If so what happens with allocations in the parent process?

As far as I know, the usual pattern for shared-memory communication is to explicitly indicate, which parts of the memory are to be shared.

As an alternative, is there a reliable way to relocate static addresses in a binary at runtime, i.e. making multiple copies to different locations on the heap?

Comment: Why not use threads?

Comment: I can't determine what you are trying to do from this.